# Reading relevant parts from JSON data

Tags: c++, json, qt

```
"{
   "count":100000,
   "data":[
            {
              "Project":null,
              "children":[  
                          {
                            "Project":null,
                            "title":"TEST",
                           }
                          ],
              "icon":false,
           }
        ]
 }"
```

I would like to read "title" : "TEST" from the JSON data. ANy help? I am  using Qt and c++ for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good JSON library that works directly with Qt, then QJson

http://qjson.sourceforge.net/usage/

Otherwise I suggest some normal JSON library.

http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: And Qt 5 has JSON built in: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/json.html